# Windows Explorer 'Can't open this item"

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-association

Even since installing DWIM Perl on a Windows 7 x64 machine, whenever I install certain programs, attempting to open most MS programs included with Windows gives me:

```
Can't open this item
It might have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Do you want to remove this item?
```

Upon uninstalling DWIM Perl, I still constantly find myself encountering this problem. What's wrong?

**EDIT:** The start menu shortcuts and the taskbar icons won't go to the program. I have to specifically search for the exe in the Start Menu.

Comment: Do you use a shortcut in Start menu to open a program? Does the .exe file the shortcut points to exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I concur with @ndev that the problem is probably corrupted
program associations of the selected file extension type.
But I do not think that his suggested .reg file completely solves the problem.

The article [Restore Default Windows 7 File Extension Type Associations](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html)
contains .reg files to correct program associations for dozens of files-types,
so not only for EXE.

Here are the contents of the [.reg file](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/123734d1312706455-default-file-type-associations-restore-default_exe.reg) to correct the EXE extension:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe]
@="exefile"
"Content Type"="application/x-msdownload"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile]
@="Application"
"EditFlags"=hex:38,07,00,00
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,2c,00,2d,00,31,00,30,00,31,00,35,00,36,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\DefaultIcon]
@="%1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open]
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"
"IsolatedCommand"="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"
"IsolatedCommand"="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runasuser]
@="@shell32.dll,-50944"
"Extended"=""
"SuppressionPolicyEx"="{F211AA05-D4DF-4370-A2A0-9F19C09756A7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runasuser\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{ea72d00e-4960-42fa-ba92-7792a7944c1d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]
@="Compatibility"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Compatibility]
@="{1d27f844-3a1f-4410-85ac-14651078412d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\DropHandler]
@="{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}"

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.exe]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.exe]
"FullDetails"="prop:System.PropGroup.Description;System.FileDescription;System.ItemTypeText;System.FileVersion;System.Software.ProductName;System.Software.ProductVersion;System.Copyright;*System.Category;*System.Comment;System.Size;System.DateModified;System.Language;*System.Trademarks;*System.OriginalFileName"
"InfoTip"="prop:System.FileDescription;System.Company;System.FileVersion;System.DateCreated;System.Size"
"TileInfo"="prop:System.FileDescription;System.Company;System.FileVersion;System.DateCreated;System.Size"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe\OpenWithList]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.exe\OpenWithProgids]
"exefile"=hex(0):

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.exe]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.exe]
@="exefile"
"Content Type"="application/x-msdownload"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.exe\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"
```

Comment: I tried it. Installing GNU Make from GNUWin caused the same errors to appear.

Comment: Other extensions might be wrong, such as .bat, but each extension has a correcting .reg file in my above link. Do you know which file this is happening on?

Comment: It is always exe files. Usually, it is the included Windows applications, like explorer and cmd and powershell.

Comment: It's real unlikely that installing Perl could destroy your Windows to that extent, but that seems to be the case. If you have a system restore point from before that, rollback to it. If not, try [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html) and let us know the results.

Comment: `sfc /scannow` says that there's nothing wrong. That occured in about Janurary, so, any restore points are too old.

Comment: Things are starting to get serious. The next step as I see it is [Repair Install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

Comment: I'm not that desperate. Might try it another time. I just wrote a Python script to kill and restart explorer.exe. Thanks for the help! Rewarding 50 repuation...

Comment: Hmmm... are you sure that you don't have installed some bad Explorer add-on ?

Comment: How would I be able to determine what addons are installed? I had installed an add-on for showing directory sizes, but that was after this started.

Comment: Use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

Comment: Also see [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/589030/windows-cannot-find-exe-some-apps-only#comment724286_589030) that looks pretty similar to your problem.

Comment: I saved a list of all addons. Here is a link: http://pastebin.com/bvRdBBEB.

Comment: I hope you checked out my [above link](http://superuser.com/questions/589030/windows-cannot-find-exe-some-apps-only#comment724286_589030). For your addons list, there are some that I don't know, but with ShellExView you can sort by the column Microsoft, select and disable all that are "No", then kill and restart explorer.exe, test and then re-enable them back. You can achieve about the same thing by booting in Safe mode. The results of these tests will tell us whether it is an addon problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your installation of Perl damaged your Windows file extension type associations.

Create a new .reg file and paste following code:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.EXE]
@="exefile"
"Content Type"="application/x-msdownload"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.EXE\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile]
@="Application"
"EditFlags"=hex:38,07,00,00
"FriendlyTypeName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,\
  00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,\
  32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,\
  00,2c,00,2d,00,31,00,30,00,31,00,35,00,36,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\DefaultIcon]
@="%1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open]
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"
"IsolatedCommand"="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"
"IsolatedCommand"="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runasuser]
@="@shell32.dll,-50944"
"Extended"=""
"SuppressionPolicyEx"="{F211AA05-D4DF-4370-A2A0-9F19C09756A7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runasuser\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{ea72d00e-4960-42fa-ba92-7792a7944c1d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]
@="Compatibility"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Compatibility]
@="{1d27f844-3a1f-4410-85ac-14651078412d}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\DropHandler]
@="{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}"

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.EXE\UserChoice]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.EXE\OpenWithProgids]
"exefile"=hex(0):
```

Now right-click on the .reg file and press Merge. You should now be able to run .exe files again. (maybe you have to restart)

If that worked Google for “windows 7 file association fixes” and fix all other damaged file associations.

Comment: Your analysis of the problem is probably correct, and your .reg file is mostly correct but not entirely safe. For example, it doesn't delete `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile` before it starts populating it. I have included a fuller .reg file in my answer, including a pointer to an article that supplies dozens of .reg files for correcting many more such association problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit Environment Variables**

Go to C:\Windows\System32\ and run SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe (because at this point you won't be able to run it from the System Properties window since it also uses the %windir% path).

Click on Environment Variables.

You'll probably see that there is already a System variable for **windir.**

It's this one that is apparently not getting resolved.

**Set the variable again as a "User" environment variable** and click Apply/OK and voila!
*Everything will magically work again!*

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. A missing path entry does not give a "Can't open this item" error.

Comment: Please give it a try and see, cause I got the same above error as he mentioned and adding the path variable did the trick!