# Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files (x86)\[...]'

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, steam, storage-pool

I have the error shown on the image when I launch Steam, Acrobat Reader, Word, PowerPoint, Excel or Citrix receiver.

[image: IMG:]

This is probably correlated: 2 days ago I tested a hard drive and connected it to my computer. I had to deleted an empty storage pool in order for it to show up in the disk management. Once it showed up, I did nothing, I just disconnected it with my computer off.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing Steam, but the same error appear when I launch it.

**Update:** I changed the name of the 'steam.exe' file to 'steam1.exe' and it does launch Steam successfully.
But when I change it back to 'steam.exe', the error shown in the image pops up again. Can anyone explain why?
And what can I do to make the Microsoft Office softwares, Acrobat Reader, and Citrix work properly again?

Comment: Judging from posts like [this one](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/1651043320666395630/), I am betting that some sort of antivirus is preventing steam.exe from running.

Comment: I don't think so, because it's not just about Steam. The Microsoft Office softwares, Acrobat Reader and Citrix receiver are also affected.

Comment: Are you running a third party AntiVirus? (aka NOT Defender).. If so, uninstall it and see if the problem goes away.  If it doesn't (and you really want the AV) reinstall it.

Comment: What happens if you create a new user account and log in & launch them?

Comment: I think I found a solution, in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/589030/windows-cannot-find-exe-some-apps-only

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old post just posting here because I had the same issue with garmin express.  And maybe it will help someone else.

when I launched garmin express I would get windows can not find C:\program files (x86)\garmin\express\express.exe

Exactly like your error above accept with Garmin.  This is not a fault with the app itself its an issue is with the image file execution options debugger in the registry.  in my case (or my clients to be more accurate) this was caused by Avast.  Ironically I had removed avast about a year ago from her computer when I took over her IT support, but as we know uninstalling does not remove all the registry entries.

To fix this issue regardless if caused by avast or not.  Open the registry.

Open the run command and type in regedit. Open the registry in administrator mode and go to
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options
Or
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
SOFTWARE
Microsoft
Windows NT
CurrentVersion
Image File Execution Options

Expand the folder for Image File Execution Options

Find the folder that corresponds to the application giving you this error and delete it.

Reboot the computer and your app should start now.

Answer (score -1):

Try opening that folder with the file explorer.

Open `This PC` and navigate to said folder, `C:\`, then `Program Files (x86)` and then `Steam`, see if the `steam.exe` file is there. It could be you're just using a broken shortcut.

Have you tried starting `Steam` through the `Start menu`?

(reputation too low to comment so I'm posting this as an answer)

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.